# Does creating multiple unique keys in a table slow down read/write times?

Tags: mysql, sql

If you create multiple unique keys in a table, would that slow down read/write times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't hurt read times much (unless you have a very low amount of RAM available) since they simply sit on the HDD/RAM but it will definitely hurt write times. For each insert/update/delete you do, the index has to be updated. If you have many indexes, many indexes will have to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

A unique key is implemented by creating an index on that column. If it is a column that you filter on, having a unique key can actually *improve* read performance as the query engine can use the index.

When writing there will be a penalty, but you will have to do a lot of updates before a unique key index (without any extra included columns) will be a bottleneck.